# Custom Post action not passing param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a a custom post request as follows:

```
= form_for(@property, :html => {:id => "promo-upload-form"} , :url => url_for(:action => 'update_promo_image'),:method => :post) do |f|
```

The route is as follows:

```
post 'properties/update_promo_image', :as => 'update_promo_image'
```

It takes me to this action on controller:

```
def update_promo_image
    @property = Property.find(params[:id])


    if @property.update(property_params)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

But I get the error:

> Couldn't find Property without an ID

If I revert this back to the standard/default Update action it works perfectly.

Does anyone have any insight as to what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: If there is no such id in url, from where you send this request, you should handly specify it like `f.hidden_field :prop_id, :value => @property.id %>` and `@property = Property.find(params[:prop_id])` in controller.

Comment: Thanks, tried this but still getting same error.

Comment: Or maybe it should be `params[:property][:prop_id]` and i suspect you are familiar with strong parameters.

Comment: Can you please post params from your console output for update_promo_image request?

Comment: @zishe Including the property id in the form isn't the way forward, it should be in the url.

Comment: he didn't noticed where form is, i thought it is perhaps on another page, inserted by partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your routes using resources and this should be easier:

routes.rb

```
resources :properties do 
  member do
    post :update_promo_image
  end
end
```

This will make an `update_promo_image_property_url(object)` route available.

View:

```
form_for(@property, :html => {:id => "promo-upload-form"} , :url => update_promo_image_property_url(@property)) do |form|
  form.input :field1
  form.submit
end
```

Which will route to your controller method (including `params[:id]` to identify the property) passing `params[:property][:field1]` for your logic. Your controller should be fine.

Comment: Glad I could help! Resource routes are very helpful, see [Routing from the outside in](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info.